# How to asses sentiment on "double negative" sentences

Tags: java, machine-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

This might be very trivial question. But, I am not able to find the answer I am looking for by doing a google or SO search.

I want to build a simple sentiment analysis logic.

There are two list of negative and positive words/phrases with some score how much negative or positive that word/phrases are.

Negative phrase/words:

```
really hate         -2
hate         -1
dislike      -1
```

Positive phrase/words:

```
like           1   
very much like 2
```

Following would be corresponding sentiment scores

```
"I like to eat Apple"          => Sentiment Score = 1
"I really hate the college president"  => Sentiment Score = -2
```

It is fine for above cases. But, I wonder how to solve following instances:

```
"Though I am an Android user, I hate to say I like iPhone 5s"
```

You see, "hate" and "like" both will make sentiment score=0
But, I expect it to be +1 because it has positive sentiment about iPhone 5s.

Comment: That example is not not a non-example of a double negative.

Comment: @farmerjoe, totally agree with you, but I couldn't figure out what to call the example. Please feel free to suggest a name to the example or edit the title appropriately.

Comment: This is not a simple sentiment problem, it's total natural language understanding (negation, context, etc.). Use a state of the art sentiment classifier and just accept that you'll get some of these awkward and unusual constructions wrong, but most of them correct.

Comment: Agreed with @BenAllison ... this is not a trivial problem at all. In fact, to tackle sentiment in examples such as the ones in this question, people have used what is known as "[Deep Learning](http://nlp.stanford.edu/sentiment/)". It's a fairly recent and active areas of NLP research.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, that is not an example of a double negative.  It is an expression of hate for the feeling about the iPhone, but it sounds like you would only like to count said feeling: the words affecting the Subject of your sentence.

You would need to have your algorithm account for context:

1. Determine the subject of your sentence. (`Apple`,`president`,`iPhone`,etc.)
2. Locate any operative keywords (`(really) hate/like/love`, etc.)
3. Score the sentence based on the operative words which apply to the subject you are concerned with.

This algorithm you can imagine is very difficult to implement as it tends towards a general comprehension of natural language.

As for double negatives you would probably want to try something like noting which words cause boolean flips to the sentiment, i.e., `not`, `don't`, etc. (most of them are contractions of `not`) and then do a count to determine the flip that it causes on the adjectives: i.e.

```
I do not like green eggs and ham
```

Identify green `eggs and ham`, backtrack to find keywords: `not, like`, maybe look for a verb, get some *sentence-like* `regex`?  Again, not the easiest task and will likely always only be accurate to a degree.

Count the `not`s and since its odd multiply your sentiment score by `-1`.

```
I do not not like green eggs and ham
```

Now we have two `nots`, its even, so we don't change the sentiment score, or multiply by `+1`.

My overall suggestion would be to either take the false-positives and carry on, or to take a look into [Natural Language Processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_language_processing)

Answer (score 1):

As your sentiment words are allowed to be phrases, the quick and dirty solution, is to add "hate to say I like" to the positive sentiment list:

```
hate to say I like   +1
```

That is one extreme solution, and the problem with it is it only handles one particular case, so you need to add thousands, if not millions, or such entries. The other extreme is a super-intelligent AI that fully understands context and nuance. The problem with that is it is beyond us, currently. Between those two extremes are NLP solutions that use grammar and patterns to understand many sentences, without having to explicitly list them all.

---

**Side note on the weight to assign**

Use `+1` if the largest match is always used, and stops other words/phrases matching those words. Otherwise adjust the weight. In this case you'd need to do nothing, as if "hate" also matches to be -1, then "like" will match to give another "+1". But for "really hate to say I like", you need to give it a base value of +2; then "really hate" will add in -2, like will add in +1, and you end up with the desired sentiment of +1.